# Could not GET gradle-3.1.3.pom android studio

Tags: android-studio-3.1.3

I have problem with android studio, I was working with it after update to 3.1.3 i give below error:

> Could not GET
>
> 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'.
>
> Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

I could download this file manually but android studio can't.

I test several way and use proxy but I can't get answer.

At last today i could solve problem, this error related to your connection i could solve this with proxy setting. google filter our Iran IP and could detect some proxy and you must use good proxy to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the thing, but with a 407 error.

Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required

"I could download this file manually but android studio can't.
I test several way and use proxy but I can't get answer."

Same here.